# Spring @Transactional - how to avoid specific exception from rolling back?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have the following method:

```
@Override
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
public void applyLog(int codFilial, List<LogLojaCentralCompactoEntity> items) {
}
```

which internally calls:

```
@Override
@Transactional(noRollbackFor = PersistenceException.class)
public void apply(LogCompactoEntity entity) {
}
```

The second method has a try/catch a PersistenceException. The problem is the transaction rolls back then it reaches PersistenceException.

I know Spring @Transactional defaults to roll back in any unchecked exception, but I am explicitly telling noRollbackFor the PersistenceException.

Why its not working? Any way to threat it?

Thanks.

Edit - the try/catch method inside apply does this:

```
try {
   insert();
}
catch(PersistenceException e)
{
   update();
}
```

Edit2 - log:

[image: Transaction Manager Log]

Edit3 - exception handling part:

```
if (acao.equalsIgnoreCase("I")) {
    try {
        insertQuery.executeUpdate();
    }
    catch(PersistenceException e) {
        int affected = updateQuery.executeUpdate();

        if(affected == 0)
            throw new LogApplyException("O insert falhou e o update não afetou registros.");
    }
}
```

Edit4 - Some more info:

1) Removing @Transactional from apply, leaving @Transaction just on applyLog results on this exception:

javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement

2) Same as 1, but adding noRollbackFor = PersistenceException.class (on applyLog) results on this exception:

org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly

Edit 5:

@lzagkaretos solution is valid (Thank you), but I want to know how to handle this for future cases.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35547482/1977152

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE

I think that relying in primary key violation exception in order to find if record should be inserted or updated is not something you should do. Another implementation you can use instead is finding before the execution if record is already saved in the database to perform an update, or not to perform an insert.

For example, if you can use spring data repositories, the code might seem like this.

```
public void apply(LogCompactoEntity entity) {

    LogCompactoEntity logCompactoEntity = (entity.getId() == null) ? new LogCompactoEntity() : logCompactoRepository.findOne(entity.getId());
    if (logCompactoEntity == null) {
        logCompactoEntity = new LogCompactoEntity();
    }

    copyProperties(entity, logCompactoEntity);

    logCompactoRepository.save(logCompactoEntity);
}
```

--

Maybe you shouldn't have a try/catch block in apply method and declare it with `throws PersistenceException` in method signature.

In order for `noRollbackFor` to work, PersistenceException has to be thrown from `apply` method. You can try the following.

```
try {
    insert();
}
catch(PersistenceException e) {
    update();
    throw e;
}
```

Comment: Does not work. If I declare noRollbackFor on the first method it throws a different exception: org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly

Comment: applyLog calls apply for each item on the List. Database access is on apply thru JPA.

Comment: You want to make sure that if PersistenceException is thrown from `insert()` method, the execution continues and completes successfully with a database commit?

Comment: Yes, first it tries to insert(), if PersistenceException is thrown because a key violation, then it calls update().

Comment: Then, you could simply omit `@Transactional(noRollbackFor = PersistenceException.class)` from `apply()` as long as you keep `try - catch` as described in the original post.

Comment: Just saw the updated log. May I ask if thrown exception is being caught in catch block?

Comment: Yes, it is. Just updated the question with the try/catch part. Can't get it to ignore the exception.

Comment: Have you omit `@Transactional(noRollbackFor = PersistenceException.class)` from `apply()` method?

Comment: Yes, but still can't get it to work. Update on the question. Thanks.

Comment: Updated answer with another suggestion.