# Spring Boot + Atomikos: Exception thrown in a transactional JMS listener inside try-catch immediately causes rollback

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-transactions, spring-jms, atomikos

I'm using `Spring Boot` 1.5.3 and `Atomikos` 4.0.6. I have a `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` setup to listen a JMS queue and handle incoming messages in a transaction using the Spring `JTATransactionManager` configured to use `Atomikos`. The message handler calls a transactional service that tries to process the message inside a `try-catch-block` and in case of exceptions calls other transactional methods for logging purposes. The idea is that the transaction should be rolled back only after everything is logged and the encountered RuntimeException is thrown from the `catch-block`.

```
@Transactional
public void handleMessage(UnmarshalledMessage message) {
    try {
        Thing thing = repository.find(message.getId());
        ...
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // NoResultException translated into EmptyResultDataAccessException
        logger.logUsingTransactions(e.getMessage());
        throw e;
    }
}
```

However, what happens that the transaction is rolled back immediately after it's originally thrown inside repository.find(). When attempting to read from the database inside the catch-block, an exception is thrown since the transaction has been marked as rollback only:

```
c.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosSQLException - Transaction is marked for rollback only or has timed out
com.atomikos.datasource.xa.session.InvalidSessionHandleStateException: Transaction is marked for rollback only or has timed out
    at com.atomikos.datasource.xa.session.NotInBranchStateHandler.checkEnlistBeforeUse(NotInBranchStateHandler.java:39)
    at com.atomikos.datasource.xa.session.TransactionContext.checkEnlistBeforeUse(TransactionContext.java:70)
    at com.atomikos.datasource.xa.session.SessionHandleState.notifyBeforeUse(SessionHandleState.java:160)
    at com.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosConnectionProxy.enlist(AtomikosConnectionProxy.java:207)
    at com.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosConnectionProxy.invoke(AtomikosConnectionProxy.java:122)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy129.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.prepareStatement(DatabaseAccessor.java:1565)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.prepareStatement(DatabaseAccessor.java:1514)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseCall.prepareStatement(DatabaseCall.java:778)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:621)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:560)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:2055)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ServerSession.executeCall(ServerSession.java:570)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ClientSession.executeCall(ClientSession.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.selectOneRow(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:714)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectOneRowFromTable(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2803)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectOneRow(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2756)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadObjectQuery.executeObjectLevelReadQuery(ReadObjectQuery.java:555)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1175)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:904)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1134)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadObjectQuery.execute(ReadObjectQuery.java:441)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1222)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2896)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1857)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1839)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1790)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.executeQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:911)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.findInternal(EntityManagerImpl.java:854)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.find(EntityManagerImpl.java:730)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.find(EntityManagerImpl.java:599)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

I'd like to know what is causing this behavior and how to resolve the issue. Note that this setup has been working correctly when run in Weblogic. For additional information, here is a transaction trace log when the exception is first encountered inside the repository method.

```
DEBUG o.s.t.jta.JtaTransactionManager - Initiating transaction commit
DEBUG o.s.t.jta.JtaTransactionManager - Creating new transaction with name [myMessageListenerContainer]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT
DEBUG o.s.t.jta.JtaTransactionManager - Participating in existing transaction
TRACE o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor - Getting transaction for [my.transactional.messagehandler.handleMessage]
DEBUG o.s.t.jta.JtaTransactionManager - Participating in existing transaction
TRACE o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor - Getting transaction for [my.repository.class.method]
TRACE o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor - Completing transaction for [my.repository.class.method] after exception: org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException: ProcessableMessage with id 443e73e7-0905-416b-9e03-4aaa2bbf09fb; nested exception is javax.persistence.NoResultException: ProcessableMessage with id [message-id]
TRACE o.s.t.i.RuleBasedTransactionAttribute - Applying rules to determine whether transaction should rollback on org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException: ProcessableMessage with id 443e73e7-0905-416b-9e03-4aaa2bbf09fb; nested exception is javax.persistence.NoResultException: ProcessableMessage with id [message-id]
TRACE o.s.t.i.RuleBasedTransactionAttribute - Winning rollback rule is: null
TRACE o.s.t.i.RuleBasedTransactionAttribute - No relevant rollback rule found: applying default rules
DEBUG o.s.t.jta.JtaTransactionManager - Participating transaction failed - marking existing transaction as rollback-only
DEBUG o.s.t.jta.JtaTransactionManager - Setting JTA transaction rollback-only
```

EDIT:

I am using `JPA` and the `NoResultException` is initially thrown in a following way:

```
public static <T> T mandatoryFind(EntityManager em, Class<T> type, Object id) throws NoResultException {
        T found = em.find(type, id);
        if (found == null) {
            throw new NoResultException(type.getSimpleName() +" with id "+ id);
        }
        return found;
}
```

Which in turn is called from a class annotated with `@Transactional(noRollbackFor = NoResultException.class)`. The exception is raised in a fairly normal use case - what I'm troubled with is why the transaction is rolled back before I can handle the exception?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you do use JPA under the hood (based on your debug logs).
This is a typical behaviour then you do query a single result.

**NoResultException:**

> Thrown by the persistence provider when Query.getSingleResult() or TypedQuery.getSingleResult()is executed on a query and there is no result to return. This exception will not cause the current transaction, if one is active, to be marked for rollback.

In order to avoid that behaviour you do query result as a `List`.

Comment: I omitted this from my question since I thought that it was not relevant but I am indeed using JPA and the NoResultException is explicitly thrown in a class annotated with @Transactional(noRollbackFor = NoResultException.class).

What is troubling me is that the transaction is rolled back before I can handle the exception.

Comment: It could be ExceptionTranslation - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35521822/norollbackfor-not-always-working-on-unchecked-exceptions-not-a-duplicate

Comment: I thought so too at one point but disabling exception translations results in the same behavior. Also, I would think that as long as the exception is handled, the transaction should not roll back regardless of rollback rules - as long as the runtime exception is not thrown outside the transactional boundaries.